# To compile and build the Open Source Opera Browser for Android

Tags: android, git, opera, chromium

I want to know about how Opera Browser for Android can be build. As I have seen this link to download [source code](http://sourcecode.opera.com/) with README.txt file saying that this is for building the code

README.txt :

> This README explains how to build a custom native library for the
>   Opera browser.
>
> 1. Prerequisites
>
> Unpack the source tarball in a directory of your choice.
>
> Install the development tools needed to build Chromium for Android as
>   described here:
>   https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions
>
> Clone the Android SDK and NDK as follows:
>
> cd chromium/src/third_party   git clone
>   https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools   cd android_tools
>   git checkout f4c36ad89b2696b37d9cd7ca7d984b691888b188
>
> 2. Compiling
>
> Enter mobile/mobile and build the chromium target. Set DEBUG to NO and
>   TARGET_ARCH to a CPU architecture, possible values are armv7 or x86.
>
> Example:
>
> cd mobile/mobile   make chromium DEBUG=NO TARGET_ARCH=armv7
>
> The output library is named libopera.so and placed in
>   mobile/mobile/chromium_libs// and
>   mobile/mobile/bin/release-generic-/assets-root/assets/lib//
>   for the compressed version.
>
> 3. Rebuilding the APK
>
> Look up the apk file name using pm path and pull it off your phone,
>   e.g.
>
> adb shell pm path com.opera.browser.beta   adb pull
>   /data/app/com.opera.browser.beta-1.apk opera.apk
>
> Use apktool from http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ to unpack it:
>
> apktool d -s opera.apk
>
> Replace the library file in the assets, using the compressed version
>   from the previous step.
>
> cp
>   bin/release-generic-armv7/assets-root/assets/lib/armeabi-v7a/libopera.so.lzma
>   \
>             opera/assets/lib/armeabi-v7a/libopera.so.lzma
>
> Build a new apk using apktool:
>
> apktool b opera -o custom.apk
>
> See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html for
>   instructions on how to sign and align the apk file.

How can we build full Opera Browser for Android ?

As this is not gonna build whole broswer.

Suggestions Please.

Comment: What do you mean it won't build the browser? It builds the APK file, which is the browser application. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Oh I see. That README is only for native libraries, not the actual browser.

Comment: Hello @cricket_007, I had followed  compilation **cd mobile/mobile make chromium DEBUG=NO TARGET_ARCH=armv7** and this not giving me any apk

Comment: @cricket_007 have you build it, If yes then please guide me for this.

Comment: No, I haven't built it, and that line explains it doesn't make the APK. It says *The output library is named libopera.so and placed in mobile/mobile/chromium_libs//*